# Solution for a TSP with Branch and Cut for Gurobi in Java?

Tags: gurobi, traveling-salesman, branch-and-cut

We have a group project and our job is to create an algorithm for solving a TSP with Branch and Cut. (Use of lazy constraints.) We tried around but don´t know what is the best way to start. We get the first solution with the nearest neighbor heuristic. From there on we should start with the solution. We should use the Gurobi solver.

What is the best way to get through this?

Answer (score 3):

There are some useful resources to use Gurobi and its callback functions to do that. In the following the first is based on Java and the second one is based on Python which can be translated to its Java equivalent.

- [Solve a traveling salesman problem on a randomly generated set of points using lazy constraints](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/examples/tsp_java.html)
- [Faster MIPs Using Custom Heuristics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dn9V2rlYUo)

Also, you might find out other helpful examples by googling, specifically, on GitHub.